# server DNS address could not be found - iis

Tags: google-chrome, iis, iis-7, iis-8

I added new site in IIS

[image]

When I'm trying open site in browser it is showing DNS error 
[image]

trying to resolve it since 5 days but I'm unable to solve this issue. please help

I'm using windows 10 OS

Answer (score 29):

It's because the host name is not recognized by the DNS server that your browser is querying looking for the IP address. You can get around this by editing your hosts file at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (there is no file extension on this file). Here's a link explaining how to edit this file: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Once you get into your hosts file, add an entry for your local website like so:

```
127.0.0.1    admin.vdeliver-local
```

Save the file, then clear your browser's cache and then you should be able to visit the site.

Comment: A note on this: in the host file using ::1 which is also, local host,  wont work in chrome but as Brandon indicated 127.0.0.1 works fine.