# This site can’t be reached - server DNS address could not be found

Tags: iis, dns

I'm having issues with a website accessing subdomains. We have several and it's starting to effect more than just one computer.

I have tried to flues / renew DNS and had no luck. This would also only work for one machine.

```
netsh winsock reset
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
```

I have also tried modifying the host file, but again this would only effect one computer and this is effecting anyone who tries to visit the site.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated! We are on Windows07 using iis

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because the host name is not recognized by the DNS server that your browser is querying looking for the IP address. You can get around this by editing your hosts file at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (there is no file extension on this file). Here's a link explaining how to edit this file: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: As I said in my question modifying the host file would only fix the one computer and not any external people visiting the site. This was solved if I remember correctly by removing all the files from the server and then reuploading them.

Comment: At least give credit to the original author of this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033434/server-dns-address-could-not-be-found-iis